# Ubuntu 14.04 customization whoopsie error

Tags: uck, whoopsie

I am trying to customize ubuntu 14.04 using uck but when i run apt-get upgrade it throws whoopsie error in uck. What could be the solultion to sort out this. Since whoopsie does not upgrade I cannot install mysql and other applications.

Comment: What customizations are you doing exactly?

Comment: i am trying to run apt-get upgrade first and then trying to install mysql-server, mysql-client but it throuws error as

Comment: /var/cache/apt/archives/whoopsie_0.2.24.6ubuntu3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)